# ImageJ Macro for converting multichannel Tiffs to Tiffs with only specified channels

Tags: tiff, imagej, imagej-macro

I have a quite simple programming question I was hoping somebody could help me with.

I'm working with Tiff files with several channels (all contained in a .lif file, which is Leica format). I want a way to easily convert all my Tiffs to Tiffs containing only a few of the channels (which I specify). Right now I'm doing it manually, for each image and it is tedious. I have no experience in writing macros and some help or a starting point would be much appreciated. I'm sure it's not a complicated macro to write.

As of now I'm using the following manual routine and commands after I have opened all my Tiffs:

1. *Image > Stacks > Stack to Images* - separates the stacked imaged into individual images
2. Close images I dont wan't to be in stack.
3. *Image > Stacks > Images to Stack* - Returns the remaining images to a stack and renames it.
4. *Image > Hyperstacks > Stack to Hyperstack* - here I change it so that the image has 3 channels.
5. Save the new Tiff with the desired channels and name.
6. Close the Tiff and repeat for all Tiffs.

What I want is a Macro that loops the above steps for all open Tiffs, letting the user specify the channels (eg. keep channels: 2,3 and 5). I know it's a very simple programming task, but I could really use some help getting it done.

Thanks!
Johannes

Answer (score 2):

There are several less complex possibilities to create a stack with only a subset of channels:

- *Image > Stacks > Tools > Make Substack...*, which lets you specify the channels/slices, and [gets recorded](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Record...) as:

  ```bs
  run("Make Substack...", "channels=1,3-5");
  ```
- *Image > Duplicate...*, where you can select a continuous range of channels, such as:

  ```bs
  run("Duplicate...", "duplicate channels=1-5");
  ```

To apply this procedure to all images in a folder, have a look at the *Process Folder* template in the [Script Editor](http://fiji.sc/Using_the_Script_Editor) (*Templates > IJ1 Macro > [Process Folder](https://github.com/fiji/Script_Editor/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/Macros/Process_Folder.ijm)*) and at the documentation on the Fiji wiki:

- [Scripting toolbox](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_toolbox#Opening.2C_processing.2C_and_saving_a_sequence_of_files_in_a_folder)
- [How to apply a common operation to a complete directory](http://fiji.sc/How_to_apply_a_common_operation_to_a_complete_directory)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed to get me started. I'll post an update when I hopefully have time to implement it and get a working macro.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help Jan Eglinger, back from vacation I managed to write the macro, which was simple with your help :) Based on the template it looks like this (I just gave them incremental names which is fine for my purpose, but could be made more allround i guess):

```
/*
 * Macro to for converting multichannel Tiffs to Tiffs with only specified channels, processes multiple images in a folder
 */

input = getDirectory("Input directory");
output = getDirectory("Output directory");

Dialog.create("File type");
Dialog.addString("File suffix: ", ".tif", 5);
Dialog.show();
suffix = Dialog.getString();

processFolder(input);

function processFolder(input) {
    list = getFileList(input);
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(File.isDirectory(input + list[i]))
            processFolder("" + input + list[i]);
        if(endsWith(list[i], suffix))
            processFile(input, output, list[i]);
    }
}

function processFile(input, output, file) {
    open(input + file);
    print("Processing: " + input + file);
    run("Make Substack...", "channels=1,2,4"); //Specify which channels should be in the final tif
    print("Saving to: " + output);
    saveAs("Tiff", output + i);
    close("*");
}
```

Comment: I added a dialog box for channels:

`Dialog.create("Channel");
Dialog.addString("Channel to extract: ", "1", 5);
Dialog.show();
channel = Dialog.getString();
`
and had to change the `run` command to `slices` instead of `channels`:

`run("Make Substack...", "slices="+channel);`